# Dynamically abbreviate words and combine with zero-padded ids to generate SKU values

Tags: php, abbreviation, sku

I am trying to create a webshop from scratch using CodeIgniter 2.x. A store have products with it's own manufacturers such as *Glock, Colt, Kalashnikov, Boker, CZ, Kizlyar, GroundZero*, etc...

I need to create the unique **SKU** *(Stock Keeping Unit)* name for each products mixed with `product.id` and `product.manufacturer`. There is no problem to do it, i.e.: **SKU** for a product with `id=13`, `manufacturer=GroundZero` and `name=Striker II` becomes: **groundzero-0013**

I need to generate the abbreviation so the SKU becomes like this: **grzr-0013** or **gnzr-0013**.

Comment: couldn't you simply do a str_replace?

Comment: yes i could, but the problem is in "abbreviation maker", do not know how to abbreviate a string programmatically

Comment: I think the best option is to store the abbreviation in db and not try to compute it.

Comment: yeah, it probably would be better but in the sake of learning, i wanted to find out the solution to make it, but thanks anyway for your advice @redreggae

Comment: I don't think we have enough understanding of your desired result from such a limited sample of input.  What should the output be from an array of words like: `['Glock', 'Colt', 'Angel', 'Kalashnikov', 'Boker', 'CZ', 'Kizlyar', 'GroundZero']`?  This question looks more like a "task" / "requirements dump".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I coded the following SKU generator depending on the specs you mentioned, you may change `$l` to make it more unique (in a way):

```
echo SKU_gen('ZeroGround', 13, 2).'<br>'; // zrgr-0013
echo SKU_gen('ZeroGround', 13, 3).'<br>'; // zrgrn-0013
echo SKU_gen('Glock', 14, 3).'<br>'; // glc-0014
echo SKU_gen('CZ', 15, 3).'<br>'; // cz-0015
echo SKU_gen('Kizlyar', 20).'<br>'; // kz-0020

function SKU_gen($string, $id = null, $l = 2){
    $results = ''; // empty string
    $vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'); // vowels
    preg_match_all('/[A-Z][a-z]*/', ucfirst($string), $m); // Match every word that begins with a capital letter, added ucfirst() in case there is no uppercase letter
    foreach($m[0] as $substring){
        $substring = str_replace($vowels, '', strtolower($substring)); // String to lower case and remove all vowels
        $results .= preg_replace('/([a-z]{'.$l.'})(.*)/', '$1', $substring); // Extract the first N letters.
    }
    $results .= '-'. str_pad($id, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); // Add the ID
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: @aspirinemaga I was in the tram and then I though what if there was no uppercase in the passed string ? So take a look at the edited code, I added ucfirst() ! To see the difference try to pass `glock` for example !

Comment: Thank you for your addition. Yes, it's not bad to have it with uppercase-free, so it would work in both way. I am a zero in regex, i thought it will find All uppercase and/or lowercase strings.